# What is difference 0x66756e63 vs 10211711099 in java

Tags: java, char, byte

I tried this code and print bytes. but this showing problem.

```
        InputStream localInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(srcName));
        int len = localInputStream.available();
        byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[len];
        localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte1, 0, len);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayOfByte1[i]);
        }
```

Result:

Plain Text: func

Hex Code: 66 75 6E 63 (in Hex editor)

Result of This code: 102 117 110 99

Why showing this problem? I waiting for answer. thank you.

Comment: Does it actually print B between the numbers?

Comment: You understand the difference between hexadecimal (base 16) and decimal (base 10) right?

Comment: crtl+R --> calc  --> enter --> View --> Programmer --> 102 --> Hex --> Eureka!

Comment: just a BTW: it is not correct to use available() in this manner. It can give you any result, must not be the total length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert a number to a string (such as by printing it, or using `String.valueOf`, or `Byte.toString`), Java (like most languages) always uses decimal by default.

If you want to print it in hex you can use `Integer.toHexString`, although note that it will not add leading zeroes - 14 becomes "E", not "0E".

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(arrayOfByte1[i]));
```

Comment: Or you can use `System.out.printf("%02bx%n", /*autoboxing*/arrayOfByte1[i]);` which will print as hex with leading zero (2 digits)